# Validate SharePoint Text Box to Limit Number of Words

Tags: validation, sharepoint

I am trying to use validation for the text bos on the SharePoint Add New form to limit number of words entered into the field. Unfortunately solution I have found on stack overflow does not work for me. I have entered

```
string-length(Status) - string-length(translate(Status, " ", "")) < 10
```

into validation rule, *Status* is the name of the text field I want to limit / validate. When I run rule inspector it is showing **Invalid Field** in red in the Validation area. The rule is not working, is displaying red warning, does not matter what I enter into the field and I cannot save entered data.. What I am doing wrong? What I have to do to have it working ???

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have received correct answer Microsoft Developers Network from Sathiya Kamalanathan. The valication which works is:

string-length(.) - string-length(translate(., " ", "")) > 10

I hope it will help others to solve similar problems.